# Происхождение слова ШОУ

Tags: английский-язык

Английское ШОУ.
Знают ли сами носители английского языка, например, британцы, откуда-есть пошло слово ШОУ (SHOW, SHEW) ?

Есть ли у кого-то из нас английский этимологический справочник, чтобы заглянуть туда?

Comment: Кажется, ничего существенного не найти.

Comment: Вам был дан ответ, но вы им не удовольствовались. Теперь сами отвечайте, на свой вкус.

Comment: По данному мне ответу заметил любопытную вещь.
Британская лингвистика не глубоко копает.
От чего бы это?
Не от молодости ли британской короны?

Comment: Поезжайте в Лондон и спросите.

Comment: Договорились.

Answer (score 0):

Английский глагол show относится к общегерманской лексике.

http://www.garshin.ru/linguistics/model/systematics/english/anglo-saxon_roots.html

Непосредственными прародителями английского народа являются **германские племена саксов, ютов, англов и фризов**, которые проникли на территорию Британии в 449 году. Так как по численности эти племена намного превосходили кельтские, то постепенно англосаксонское наречие полностью вытеснило кельтское наречие из употребления.

http://www.native-english.ru/articles/history

Answer (score 0):

От ср-англ. sheuen, shouen > староангл. scêawian - смотреть, показывать.
Вопрос невежлив, ибо неуместен. Носители не знают, как ты не знаешь о родстве быка и пчелы и слова врач от др.-русс. врати. Такие вопросы к специалистам, но даже не к грамотным носителям. 
То, что знает этимолог, не обязательно нужно ждать от прекрасного препод. русск. яз.

---

show verb
showed, shown or  showed
shew - архаич. show